# How can i access a file (say .xml) from a native code,invoked from an android activity class, where do i need to place that XML file?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying out an example of OpenCV from http://github.com/billmccord/OpenCV-Android and am stuck at the point where it is mentioned "Before attempting to run the VideoEmulator application, you must first copy this XML file into the emulator in the following location: /data/data/org.siprop.opencv/files/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml "

Where in my eclipse workspace do I need to place this haar xml file to be copied to the location /data/data/org.siprop.opencv/files/ of the emulator?

The library "libopencv.so" when placed under libs/amreabi in the eclipse workspace, is picked and appropriately placed under data/data/org.siprop.opencv/lib as seen from the fileexplorer via DDMS

Answer (score 0):

This is location not in Eclipse workspace, but in emulator/phone filesystem. Try to place this haar xml file into this folder via DDMS, for example.

Comment: Thanks Sergey!!! A drag drop of this XML into the emulator filesystem did it. I however cannot find this haar xml packaged within the .apk file. I pulled this .apk from the emulator file system /data/app/org.siprop.opencv.apk